Where to setup colors in ubuntu terminal
I have unreadable hihglights in ubuntu terminal (I use set -o vi)
i.e. awk:

How to adjust colors in code in default terminal ubuntu?

You can use the GNOME Terminal Documentation or try to adjust the color schemes in this way:


